# Run External exe from UWP app, workaround sandboxed mode

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, launcher, windows-10-iot-core

I have a program where i want to have the ability to launch a local application (for example Spotify) from my UWP App. I have searched the web for a solution as (Process.Start()) doesn't work. As i have understood the UWP applications is kind of sandboxed for saftey and stability reasons. But is there a (simpel) way to work around this.

I only want the ability to start and close a program inside my own frame/Window. No need to interact/send/recive data between my applications and the external program

Comment: Let's stop a minute here and think. If there was a simple way out of the sandbox, what would be the point of having a sandbox in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a program where i want to have the ability to launch a local
>   application (for example Spotify) from my UWP App.

You can utilize `Windows.System.ProcessLauncher` API.

Here is a sample about [how to launch an external process (exe) from a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-iotcore-samples/tree/dcd29b87bacd4c7d11b4407ff7b38a9965fa6fa6/Samples/ExternalProcessLauncher) you can reference.

Make sure **add systemManagement capabiity**.

For more information reference [Process​Launcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.processlauncher).

Comment: This is only available when targetting the IoT device family, so you can't use this in a desktop or mobile environment, which is where Spotify is.

Comment: The link to the sample is not valid any more.

Answer (score 5):

That is not possible with all apps.  Some desktop apps handle protocol launches and that can be a way of launching another app.  Spotify actually has a protocol registered so you could do this to launch it:

```
await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("spotify:"));
```

Comment: If you want to run a particular Windows Form application, how could you know which the URI is named?

Comment: If a desktop app registers a protocol handler, it will be in the registry.